# Return whether an array of values exists in a column?

Tags: sql-server, arrays, return, exists

Lets say I have a table: T

```
Id    Val
==========
1     100
2     200
3     300
```

I want to check if every element in an array, like (400, 200, 100, 700, 900), exists in the above table, the expected results are:

```
(0, 1, 1, 0, 0) or (false, true, true, false, false)
```

Any idea how to write the select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.val IS NULL 
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END value_exists
  FROM 
(
  SELECT 400 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 200 UNION ALL
  SELECT 100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 700 UNION ALL
  SELECT 900
) a LEFT JOIN Table1 t 
    ON a.val = t.val
```

Output:

```
| VALUE_EXISTS |
----------------
|            0 |
|            1 |
|            1 |
|            0 |
|            0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ccbba/6)** demo

Comment: @user2006633 You're very welcome :) If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could say Select * from T WHERE Val=400 or Val=200 etc. Then map the results to the array. The ones that do map are true and the ones that don't are false.